# React Native create blob from arbitrary data

Tags: javascript, react-native, blob

I have a React Native (0.59) app which consumes an (Swagger-generated) SDK that accepts `Blob` objects for file uploads. While there are sources on creating blobs from remote resources (e.g. using fetch), I couldn't find any resource on creating a blob on the fly. For example I have a string (regular JS string), and I need to upload that string as a text file to the server. I'll also have other file references from the file system where I'll also need to upload too.

How do I create Blob from any kind of arbitrary data in React Native?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried the rn-fetch-blob package in react-native? I used this package for uploading image with the firebase as follows, it might help you.

```
import { firebase } from '../config';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;

window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;

export const uploadImage = (uri, mime, uid) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;

    let uploadBlob = null;

    const imageRef = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref('profileImg')
      .child(uid);
    fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
      .then(data => {
        return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
      })
      .then(blob => {
        uploadBlob = blob;
        return imageRef.put(uploadUri, { contentType: mime });
      })
      .then(() => {
        uploadBlob.close();
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      })
      .then(url => {
        resolve(url);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: What React Native and RNFetchBlob versions are you using? There is no method named `Blob.build` in mine. The `Blob` methods are `close`, `getRNFetchBlobRef`, `markAsDerived`, `onCreated`, `readBlob`, and `slice`.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu It is old one, Can I see your code? Actually you could just send your image to your server as base64 with proper content type or you could use [this package](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) pick image from gallery and get the base64 then send post request to your server with the data.

Comment: I'm using an external library (created internally by the company that I work with) which accepts a `Blob`, so those options are unfortunately not possible.

Comment: Oh, after further investigation I've found out that `Blob.build` *is* actually there, it's just IntelliSense that wasn't aware of it. It highlights my code complaining about `Blob.build` not existing, but it works at runtime.