# 3D model renderer component not loading file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, three.js, react-redux

I'm working on a feature for a web app I'm developing that consists in a .obj model viewer. The thing is that I don't really know how to work with the three.js library so I decided to go with a dependency to do the trick, I'm using [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-3d-viewer). Basically what I'm doing is to get the content of the file in the redux state which is initially obtained by a backend request, so, I ultimately use the state variable and pass it a component prop to the `<OBJModel />` component, but I get this error when trying to load:
https://pasteboard.co/Jtdkigq.png
https://pasteboard.co/JtdkPoRk.png

This is the front-end code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { OBJModel } from 'react-3d-viewer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getModel } from './../../actions';
import golem from './../../Stone.obj';

class ModelViewer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.querySelector('#upload-modal').style.display = 'flex';
    let id = '';
    let slashCounter = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < window.location.pathname.length; i++) {
      if (slashCounter === 2) {
        id = id + window.location.pathname[i];
      }
      if (window.location.pathname[i] === '/') {
        slashCounter++;
      }
    }
    this.props.getModel(id);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.model.previewModel)
      console.log(this.props.model.previewModel);
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        {!this.props.model.previewModel ? null : (
          <OBJModel
            height="500"
            width="500"
            position={{ x: undefined, y: -5, z: undefined }}
            src={this.props.model.previewModel}
          />
        )}
        <div id="upload-modal" className="upload-modal">
          <div className="upload-modal-content">
            <p className="upload-modal-header">
              <i
                className="exclamation circle icon"
                style={{ color: 'gray' }}
              />
              Loading model...
            </p>
            <div
              className="ui indicating progress active progress-indicator"
              id="upload-bar-indicator"
            >
              <div className="bar" id="upload-bar">
                <div className="progress" id="modal-upload-progress"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { model: state.model };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getModel })(ModelViewer);
```

This is the action function that makes the request to the backend:

```
export const getModel = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const config = {
      onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        let percentCompleted = Math.round(
          (progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total
        );
        document.querySelector(
          '#modal-upload-progress'
        ).innerHTML = `${percentCompleted}%`;
        document.querySelector(
          '#upload-bar'
        ).style.width = `${percentCompleted}%`;
        document
          .querySelector('#upload-bar-indicator')
          .setAttribute('data-percent', `${percentCompleted}`);
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://hushpuppys-3d-hub-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/modelfiles/${id}.obj`,
      config
    );

    document.querySelector('#upload-modal').style.display = 'none';

    dispatch({ type: 'GET_MODEL', payload: response.data.data });
  };
};
```

This is the controller that downloads the file from the Cloud Storage where im storing the files:

```
exports.fileDownloaderController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fileName = req.params.id;
    const config = {
      headers: { Authorization: credentials.authorizationToken },
    };

    await axios
      .get(
        `${credentials.downloadUrl}/file/hushpuppys-3d-hub-storage/${fileName}`,
        config
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        res.status(200).json({
          status: 'success',
          data: response.data,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err); // an error occurred
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
};
```

And this is how the downloaded files look like when they are downloaded from the server, and logged in the console:

https://pasteboard.co/JtdpMCi.png

Comment: Are you putting the downloaded file into the `src` of that 3D viewer component? Because I'm pretty sure the component you are using needs the URL to that resource, not the data. I'm also pretty sure that componeent internally will just use `new OBJLoader().load( url )` and not `new OBJLoasder().parse( url )`. If you feed that string that is your object into a URL, the `XMLHttpRequest` would fail, which is what your error looks like, making it a _very long_ error. It looks like it's trying to navigate to a URL consisting of the contents of your model...

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the three.js documentation and I was taling a look at the dependency files to see if I could figure out something and I pretty much ended understanding that the src is supposed to be a path string as you say. In that case, do you have any idea on how to make it work with those parameters? Given the fact that the content of the file is being received as a string variable which is contained in the redux state

Comment: Perhaps with a Blob...? I can't give you the implementation *hacen't done that in a while now) but you should be able to turn the data you received into a `Blob`, which can be loaded as if it's a URL, or turned into a URL. All you need to find is something to turn arbitrary data into a URL (again, I would need a refresher on Blobs). Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314070/react-native-create-blob-from-arbitrary-data?